# Solve the following equation $x^3-3x=\sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the following equation $$x^3-3x=\sqrt{x+2}$$
> without squaring of the both sides.

The domain is $x\geq-2$ but what is the rest?

For example, after squaring of the both sides we obtain:
$$(x^3-3x)^2=x+2$$ with $x(x-\sqrt3)(x+\sqrt3)\geq0$, which gives $$x^6-6x^4+9x^2-x-2=0.$$
Since $$2^6-6\cdot2^4+9\cdot2^2-2-2=0,$$ we can get a factor $x-2$, but the rest is not so easy.

Id est, it's better to find a solution without squaring.

Thank you!

Comment: By inspection, I would note that $x=2$ solves the equation (the $\sqrt{ }$ denotes positive square root, I presume).

Comment: You could let $x+2=y^2$ and try to factor the resulting sextic. That will still leave a not-so-nice cubic to solve, with roots in range.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint:

Set $x=2\cos2y,0\le2y\le\pi\  \  \ \  (1)$

$$\cos6y=\cos y$$

$\implies6y=2m\pi\pm y$ where $m$ is any integer.

Choose $m$ such that $(1)$ is satisfied

Comment: Why did you choose 2cos 2y ? why not anything else ?

Comment: Neat (+1) with the note that this only covers roots in $[-2,2]\,$, so to turn the hint into a proof would need an addendum as to why roots $\gt 2$ don't exist.

Comment: @A---B, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0/2157645#2157645  also $\sqrt{x+2}$ finds a nice shape by the substitution.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Your idea is very nice, but what happens if $x>2$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, Let me try to figure out. If $$f(x)=x^3-3x-\sqrt{x+2}, f'(x)>0$$ for $x\ge2$

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1**: $\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x^2+x-1)(x^3+x^2-2x-1) = 0$

**Idea 2**:$\Leftrightarrow (x^3-3x-2)+(2-\sqrt{x+2})=0$

$\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x^2+2x+1)- \frac{x-2}{2+\sqrt{x+2}}=0$

$\Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x^2-2x+1-\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+2}}) = 0$