# An interesting Cubic equation $x^3-3x-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

For the cubic equation $x^3-3x-1=0$, you can check it has three real roots by calculus knowledge. Let them be $x_1<x_2<x_3$. Now prove that
$$x_3^2-x_2^2=x_3-x_1.$$ 
It is not difficult to check that:
$$x_1=2\cos 140 ^{\circ},x_2=2\cos 100 ^{\circ},x_3=2\cos 20 ^{\circ}.$$
(Here use the formula: $\cos 3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x.$ )

And then we can check:
$$x_3^2-x_2^2=x_3-x_1.$$
I just want to know how to get: $x_1=2\cos 140 ^{\circ},x_2=2\cos 100 ^{\circ},x_3=2\cos 20 ^{\circ}.$ Is there some trick. Any help and hint will welcome.

Comment: For cubic equations, you can use Cardano's Formula:
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cardano_formula

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0/2157645#2157645 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203364/solve-the-following-equation-x3-3x-sqrtx2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the formula $\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)$ is actually quite useful, but first we have to do $x=2y$, then we get
$$8y^3 - 6y - 1 = 0$$
Now we have the 4:-3 ratio and we can substitute $y=\cos(\theta)$ to get, from the above formula,
$$2\cos(3\theta) = 1$$
and from there we can get cosine form of the roots.

Answer (score 3):

Since the roots are of the form $\cos(\theta)$, make the substitution $x=t+t^{-1}$ and expand to get

$$P(t+t^{-1})=\frac {t^6-t^3+1}{t^3}=\frac {t^9+1}{t^3(t^3+1)}$$
Set the above expression equal to zero and it's easy to see that$$t^9=-1$$Let $t=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and expand to see that$$\theta=\frac {\pi(2k+1)}{9}$$where $k=0,2,3,\ldots$. Hence$$x=t+t^{-1}=2\cos\left(\frac {\pi(2k+1)}9\right)$$