# Show there can't be two real and distinct roots of polynomial $f(x)=x^3-3x+k$ in $(0,1)$, for any value of k.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I have two proofs here one which I did and the other was given in book. Is one better than the other? I am asking for in an exam setting which proof makes a better solution(as in fetch more marks).

### Proof 1 (My proof)

$f'(x)=3x^2-3$, in the interval $(0,1)$ is less than $0$. If there were two distinct roots then $f'(0)$ should have been $0$ once in $(0,1)$ by rolle's theorem. Since it isn't there are no values of $k$ for which there are two real roots.

### Proof 2 (Book)

Let $a,b$ be two roots of $f(x)$ in $(0,1)$ then there exists a $c$ such the $f'(c) = 0$ for c in $[a,b] $ by Rolle's theorem. $f'(c)= 3c^2-3$ has no solutions in $(0,1)$ hence there is no such value of $k$.

Comment: Yours is better because the book version has a wrong expression for $f'$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0/2157645#2157645

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen that's a typo sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both solutions are equally valid and should both get full marks.

Personally, I found your solution easier to follow though, but in an exam situation as long as what you’re doing is clear, a correct proof will achieve full marks regardless.