# Real roots of $f(x)=8x^3-6x+1$ given in complex form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The function $f (x) = 8x^3-6x + 1$ has three real roots as it is easy to check (a quick way is to see the graph of f). However, Wolfram gives  the following exact values as roots:

[image]

There is no Wolfram error here because if asked for approximate root values, it gives the real numbers $-0.93969,0.17365$ and $0.76604$.

In sum, each of the three exact values when simplified must give a real number. I have tried to find at least one of these three values but it was not possible in a first attempt. Can someone describe a method to do it?

Comment: See my method in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2157643/how-can-i-solve-the-equation-x3-x-1-0

Comment: Note that $e^{i \pi/3}=\dfrac{1+i\sqrt3}2$

Comment: J.W. Tanner:- Thanks you very much.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee.- Very kind Thanks you.

Comment: More simple form $2x=t$, $$t^3-3t+1=0$$

Comment: @lonestudent: ironically, this makes the resolution more difficult !

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right! :) When I look at your answer, the original equation actually tells us "solve me in a trigonometric way" :)

Answer (score 4):

This phenomenon is called [Casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).  You cannot express the real roots in terms of real-valued radicals; however, a trigonometric expression is possible.

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known fact.

Comment: I did not know this well-known fact ("I know that I know nothing")

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in fact very easy to solve (it was probably arranged to be so). Rewrite as

$$4x^3-3x=-\frac12$$

and compare to the trigonometric formula

$$\cos3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta.$$

> $$3\theta=\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi,k=0,1,2,\\x=\cos\theta.$$

This is a case of angle trisection.

---

Note that by a simple rescaling of the variable, you can generalize to all equations of the form $$px^3+qx+r=0$$ that have three solutions.